# Jenkins won't recognize local commands

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rvm, appium

I'm attempting to integrate my Ruby/Cucumber/Appium test framework with our Jenkins environment.

On the local machine I have installed RVM to utilize ruby 2.4, the newest appium, cucumber, and I'm attempting to use the already-installed ruby gems for my jenkins jobs.

How do I get the Jenkins shell to utilize my local RVM instance? I don't want to have to install rvm, cucumber, and appium every time I run a job.

I have already attempted to add environment variables in the Jenkins settings but it still does not recognize my commands.

Note my admin has deleted the automatically generated jenkins user.

Comment: you can set the rvm in your environmental path and same you can use in your jenkins configuration setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably want something like this in "Execute shell":

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
rvm use 2.4
bundle install
bundle exec rake
```

you mention that your jenkins user is gone. the above assumes that there is an rvm setup in the `$HOME` directory of the user running your builds, so if that's not certain, or you don't know what user is executing your builds, you probably want to start there, `echo $USER`, and so on, and see if rvm works for that user outside of a jenkins build.